# how to classify data inside a list file

Tags: r

I have a data looks like this

```
df<- structure(list(14, FALSE, c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 
13, 6), c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 0), c(0, 1, 2, 
3, 4, 12, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11), c(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 12, 5, 6, 
7, 8, 9, 10, 11), c(0, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 
12, 13), c(0, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13
), list(c(1, 0, 1), structure(list(), names = character(0)), 
    list(name = c("Bestman", "Tera1", "Tera2", "Tera3", "Tera4", 
    "Tera5", "Tetra", "Brownie1", "Brownie2", "Brownie3", "Brownie4", 
    "Brownie5", "Brownie6", "Brownie7")), list()), <environment>), class = "igraph")
```

I am trying to make a list and assign the two core as root

I can easily do this

```
as_tbl_graph(df) %>%
    activate(nodes) %>%
    mutate(type = ifelse(name %in% c("Bestman", "Tetra"), "root", "branch")) %>%
    mutate(group = ifelse(name == "Bestman" | grepl("Tera", name),
                          "Bestman", "Tera"))
```

when the number of core grows, this method does not work, for example if I have more and I do the following

for example when my data becomes like this

```
df2<-structure(list(28, FALSE, c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 1, 2, 8, 7, 9, 
10, 11, 7, 7, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 26, 
27, 7, 12, 18, 25, 12, 18, 25, 18, 25, 25), c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 7, 6, 7, 7, 7, 2, 1, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 18, 18, 18, 
18, 18, 18, 25, 25, 0, 0, 0, 0, 7, 7, 7, 12, 12, 18), c(6, 0, 
7, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 28, 14, 13, 9, 8, 10, 11, 12, 29, 32, 15, 16, 
17, 18, 19, 30, 33, 35, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 31, 34, 36, 37, 
26, 27), c(6, 0, 7, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 28, 29, 30, 31, 14, 13, 9, 
8, 10, 11, 12, 32, 33, 34, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 35, 36, 20, 21, 
22, 23, 24, 25, 37, 26, 27), c(0, 0, 2, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 12, 13, 
14, 15, 16, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 
36, 37, 38), c(0, 12, 13, 14, 14, 14, 14, 15, 22, 22, 22, 22, 
22, 29, 29, 29, 29, 29, 29, 36, 36, 36, 36, 36, 36, 36, 38, 38, 
38), list(c(1, 0, 1), structure(list(), names = character(0)), 
    list(name = c("Bestman", "Tera1", "Tera2", "Tera3", "Tera4", 
    "Tera5", "Brownie2", "Tetra", "Brownie1", "Brownie3", "Brownie4", 
    "Brownie5", "trueG", "ckage1", "ckage2", "ckage3", "ckage4", 
    "ckage5", "Carowner", "Hoghet1", "Hoghet2", "Hoghet3", "Hoghet4", 
    "Hoghet5", "Hoghet6", "Bestwomen", "Esme2", "Esme3")), list()), 
    <environment>), class = "igraph")

as_tbl_graph(df2) %>%
    activate(nodes) %>%
mutate(type = ifelse(name %in% c("Bestman", "Tetra", "trueG", "Carowner","Bestwomen"), "root", "branch")) %>%
     mutate(group = ifelse(name == "Bestman" | grepl("Tetra", name) | grepl("trueG",name) | grepl("Carowner", name) | grepl("Bestwomen", name) ,                       "Bestman", "Tetra","trueG","Carowner","Bestwomen" ))
```

I get error, I want to know what I am doing wrong here ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your second graph is more complex than your first. Some of the 'peripheral' nodes join more than one central node, so it is not clear how they should be labelled / colored. However, tidygraph has various grouping functions which can be used to assign the nodes to groups based on their connectivity, and the centrality of a node can be calculated automatically to help with labelling and sizing.

```r
library(tidygraph)
library(ggraph)

df2 %>%
  as_tbl_graph() %>%
  activate(nodes) %>%
  mutate(is_central = centrality_hub() > 0.6) %>%
  mutate(group = factor(group_label_prop())) %>%
  ggraph(layout = "igraph", algorithm = "nicely") +
  geom_edge_link(width = 2, alpha = 0.1) +
  geom_node_circle(aes(r = ifelse(is_central, nchar(name)/12, 0.1), fill = group),
                   color = NA) +
  geom_node_text(aes(label = ifelse(is_central, name, '')), size = 5,
                 color = "gray40", family = "Roboto Condensed", fontface = 2) +
  theme_graph() +
  coord_equal() +
  scale_fill_brewer(palette = "Pastel2", guide = "none")
```

[image]

Comment: what this one does? `scale_fill_brewer(palette = "Pastel2", guide = "none")` the second I add this in a bigger dataset, it gives me warning and no name basically printed

Comment: these are part of the warnings `Warning messages:
1: In grid.Call.graphics(C_text, as.graphicsAnnot(x$label), x$x, x$y,  :
  no font could be found for family "Roboto Condensed"
2: In grid.Call.graphics(C_text, as.graphicsAnnot(x$label), x$x, x$y,  :
  no font could be found for family "Roboto Condensed"
3: In grid.Call.graphics(C_text, as.graphicsAnnot(x$label), x$x, x$y,  :
  no font could be found for family "Roboto Condensed"
4: In grid.Call.graphics(C_text, as.graphicsAnnot(x$label), x$x, x$y,  :
  no font could be found for family "Roboto Condensed"`

Comment: @nik again, you need to remove the `family = 'Roboto Condensed'` - this is where the warning is coming from. You don't need the `scale_fill_brewer`, - it just makes the colors prettier.

Comment: it recognizes 7 groups that I have, once I add this `geom_node_text(aes(label = ifelse(is_central, name, '')), size = 5,
                 color = "gray40", fontface = 2)` it prints two of the names and ignore the rest but it still shows 7 groups and 7 different nodes , any idea where the problem could be?

Comment: You may need to increase the centrality_hub threshold. Try 0.5 instead of 0.6 - you may need to play about to get the correct value.

Answer (score 0):

ifelse only allows for two options, try using `dplyr::case_when` instead.
https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/case_when.html

Update to add requested code:

```
mutate(group = dplyr::case_when(name == "Bestman" ~ "Bestman",
                         grepl("Tetra", name) ~ "Tetra",
                         grepl("trueG",name) ~ "trueG",
                         grepl("Carowner", name) ~ "Carowner",
                         grepl("Bestwomen", name) ~ "Bestwomen"))
```

Comment: any solution? if you can give me a solution and I accept your answer

Comment: This just leaves the names as they are though?

Comment: Unless I’m misunderstanding that if else statement it should change them how they want it - that’s the main change between the two statements no?